# Создания компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Хочу создать компонент для его повторного вызова
Компонент не работает ((

```js
Vue.component('v-app', {
  template: `
  <div class="show-modal" v-show="itemPost" >
   <h1>Item-Post</h1>
   {{ item.userId }} <br>
   {{ item.id }} <br>
   {{ item.title }} <br>
   {{ item.body }} <br>
  </div>
  `
 });
 let semple=new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      userId: '',
      id: '',
      title: '',
      body: '',
      posts: null,

      item: '',
      itemPost: false
  },
  methods: {
  Puslished(){
    this.posts.push({
     userId:this.userId, 
     id:this.id,
     title:this.title,
     body:this.body
    });
   },
  clickBookModal(i) {
    this.itemPost = true;
    this.item = this.posts[i]
   },
  DeleteItemPost(i) { 
    this.posts.splice(i, 1);
   }
  },
  mounted() {
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
   .then(response => this.posts=response.data);
  }
 })
```

```css
.post-wrapper ul{
 margin: 5px;
 width: 120px;
 border: 2px solid orange;
}

.post-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

 <input type="text" placeholder="userId" v-model="userId">
 <input type="text" placeholder="id" v-model="id">
 <input type="text" placeholder="title" v-model="title">
 <input type="text" placeholder="body" v-model="body">
 <div v-show="userId"><b>UserId</b> -{{ userId }}</div>
 <div v-show="id"><b>Id</b> -{{ id }}</div>
 <div v-show="title"><b>Title</b> -{{ title }}</div>
 <div v-show="body"><b>Body</b> -{{ body }}</div>

 <button @click="Puslished">Push in Posts</button>
 

 <!-- SHOW ON CLICK ITEM -->
 <v-app></v-app>
 
 <!-- show -->

 <div class="post-wrapper">
  <ul v-for="(post, i) in posts" class="box" @click="clickBookModal(i)">
   <li  v-html="post.userId" class="user-id"></li>
   <li  v-html="post.id" class="post-id"></li>
   <li  v-html="post.title" class="post-title"></li>
   <li  v-html="post.body" class="post-body"></li>
   <button @click="DeleteItemPost(i)">Delete!</button>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос.

Comment: уточнил вопрос )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Входные параметры** — это пользовательские атрибуты, которые вы можете
>   установить на компоненте. Когда значение передаётся в атрибут входного
>   параметра, оно становится свойством экземпляра компонента.

```
<v-app :item="item" v-show="itemPost" @close="closeBookModal"></v-app>
```

и

```
Vue.component('v-app', {
props: ['item'],
    template: `
    <div class="show-modal">
        <h1>Item-Post</h1>
        {{ item.userId }} <br>
        {{ item.id }} <br>
        {{ item.title }} <br>
        {{ item.body }} <br>
    </div>
    `
});
```

Использовал информацию по ссылке - [Передача данных в дочерние компоненты через входные параметры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Рабочий пример:

```js
Vue.component('v-app', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `
  <div class="show-modal">
   <h1>Item-Post</h1>
   {{ item.userId }} <br>
   {{ item.id }} <br>
   {{ item.title }} <br>
   {{ item.body }} <br>
      <button @click="$emit('close')">Close</button>
  </div>
  `
});
let semple = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userId: '',
    id: '',
    title: '',
    body: '',
    posts: null,

    item: '',
    itemPost: false
  },
  methods: {
    Puslished() {
      this.posts.push({
        userId: this.userId,
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title,
        body: this.body
      });
    },
    clickBookModal(i) {
      this.itemPost = true;
      this.item = this.posts[i]
    },
    closeBookModal() {
      this.itemPost = false;
      this.item = null;
    },
    DeleteItemPost(i) {
      this.posts.splice(i, 1);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => this.posts = response.data);
  }
})
```

```css
.post-wrapper ul {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.post-wrapper ul:hover {
  border-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.show-modal {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <input type="text" placeholder="userId" v-model="userId">
  <input type="text" placeholder="id" v-model="id">
  <input type="text" placeholder="title" v-model="title">
  <input type="text" placeholder="body" v-model="body">
  <div v-show="userId"><b>UserId</b> -{{ userId }}</div>
  <div v-show="id"><b>Id</b> -{{ id }}</div>
  <div v-show="title"><b>Title</b> -{{ title }}</div>
  <div v-show="body"><b>Body</b> -{{ body }}</div>

  <button @click="Puslished">Push in Posts</button>


  <!-- SHOW ON CLICK ITEM -->
  <v-app :item="item" v-show="itemPost" @close="closeBookModal"></v-app>

  <!-- show -->

  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <ul v-for="(post, i) in posts" class="box" @click="clickBookModal(i)">
      <li v-html="post.userId" class="user-id"></li>
      <li v-html="post.id" class="post-id"></li>
      <li v-html="post.title" class="post-title"></li>
      <li v-html="post.body" class="post-body"></li>
      <button @click.stop="DeleteItemPost(i)">Delete!</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```